# Can't binding ObservableCollection to ListView on Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

so I get a problem a binding item to listview

Initialization page

```
public HomePage()
    {
        Acquaintances = Add();
        //InitializeToolbar();
        InitializeComponent();

    }
private ObservableCollection<Acquaintance> Add()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Acquaintance>()
        {

         new Acquaintance(){.....}
```

On XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="lstUser" BackgroundColor="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Acquaintances}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding PhotoUrl}" Height="50"></ImageCell>

                        </Grid>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="5">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding JobTitle}" FontSize="10" TextColor="#CCCCCC"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

ListView can't be binding Acquaintances to items source of ListView. Where is wrong???

In Page:

```
public ObservableCollection<Acquaintance> Acquaintances { get; }
```

Comment: have you set BindingContext?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.

Comment: BindingContext = Acquaintances;

Comment: if you set the BindingContext = Acquaintances, then your binding expression should be ItemsSource="{Binding .}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are forgetting to set the `BindingContext` property on your page. Without setting that property, the page does not know where to get data from.

To set your context to itself, do it like this:

```
public HomePage()
{
    Acquaintances = Add();
    //InitializeToolbar();
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = this; // Note that I added this line
}
```

In the comments you are asking why it fails when you set `BindingContext = Acquaintances;` and why it works when you set `BindingContext = this;`.

It is simple, set the `BindingContext` to the object holding properties that you want to access. By setting the context to `this`, which is in this case `HomePage`, you can use bindings such as `{Binding Acquaintances}`. Because `Acquaintances` is a property of `HomePage`.

If you set the `BindingContext` to a specific property, which can also be a complex type but doesn't have to be, you change the scope. So when you set the `BindingContext` to `Acquaintances`, you will have to change the `ItemsSource` on your list to `{Binding .}`. The dot means that it will use the object in the `BindingContext` itself, not a property that is in it.

Comment: BindingContext = Acquaintances; => fails
BindingContext = this; => success

Why?

Comment: Updated the answer, I hope it clarifies a bit for you. Please don't forget to accept it if it helped.